# xauth on Oracle Linux 6.8 constantly fails with "xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority"

Tags: centos, xauth

Newly installed Oracle Linux 6.8 (actually a RHEL/CentOS 6.8 release underneath), yum install xorg-x11-xauth, `xauth list` , `xauth generate`, all xauth commands involve $HOME/.Xauthority file fail with `xauth:  error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority`.
I have these 3 files:

```
[root@oracle11 ~]# ll .Xauthority*
-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Dec  7 09:45 .Xauthority
-rw-------. 2 root root 0 Dec  7 09:45 .Xauthority-c
-rw-------. 2 root root 0 Dec  7 09:45 .Xauthority-l
```

After some search I saw .Xauthority file is of proper attribute. why do these happen?
I also tried these with users other than root, same.